# How to use single page application in SPFx with react

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, react

I am trying to create a single page application in SPFx using react.

When I am using React routing, I am facing below problem:

[image]

How to create a single page application in SPFx using react?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not pass the web part context (`this.context`) from main web part file (`.ts` file) to your react component file (`.tsx` file).

You have to pass the web part context to `props` of react component class.

Check detailed steps in below threads:

1. [SPHttpClient undefined error: Using React JS to add item in SharePoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270646/sphttpclient-undefined-error-using-react-js-to-add-item-in-sharepoint-list)
2. [SharePoint Framework - CRUD Operations Using ReactJS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-crud-operations-using-react-js/)